# How to correctly configure SQLite thread_safe mode

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to compile SQLite in Xcode as a static library to use in the iOS project. The project is multiplatform and we have one common part written in c++, where SQLite is used. That's why I cannot go with a iOS standard.

I stuck with a very simple problem - after I compile the library and use it in my code, sqlite3_threadsafe() returns 2 even though I set mode 1.
I set the mode in the field "Other C Flags" of Build Settings in Xcode by writing flag DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=1

[image: Xcode Build Settings]

What could be the problem? I tried everything, but seems like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

By default Xcode compiles Sqlite in the way that it supports multithread and serial modes so there's no need to use compiler flags. Instead you have to enable it in your code before you initialize your sqlite3* instance:

```
sqlite3_shutdown();
if (sqlite3_threadsafe() > 0) {
    int retCode = sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);
    if (retCode == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Can now use sqlite on multiple threads, using the same connection");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"setting sqlite thread safe mode to serialized failed!!! return code: %d", retCode);
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Your SQLite database is not compiled to be threadsafe.");
}
sqlite3_initialize();
```